# Querying a many:many relationship on PK of the related table (ie. filtering by related table column)

Tags: postgresql, graphql, postgraphile

I have a many:many relationship between 2 tables: `note` and `tag`, and want to be able to search all notes by their `tagId`. Because of the many:many I have a junction table `note_tag`.

My goal is to expose a computed field on my Postgraphile-generated Graphql schema that I can query against, along with the other properties of the `note` table.

I'm playing around with `postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter`. This plugin makes it possible to filter by things like authorId (which would be 1:many), but I'm unable to figure out how to filter by a many:many. I have a computed column on my note table called `tags`, which is JSON. Is there a way to "look into" this json and pick out where id = 1?

Here is my computed column `tags`:

```
    create or replace function note_tags(note note, tagid text)
        returns jsonb as $$
            select
                json_strip_nulls(
                    json_agg(
                        json_build_object(
                            'title', tag.title, 
                            'id', tag.id,
                        ) 
                    )
                )::jsonb 
            from note
            inner join note_tag on note_tag.tag_id = tagid and note_tag.note_id = note.id
            left join note_tag nt on note.id = nt.note_id 
            left join tag on nt.tag_id = tag.id
            where note.account_id = '1'
            group by note.id, note.title;
        $$ language sql stable;
```

as I understand the function above, I am returning jsonb, based on the tagid that was given (to the function): `inner join note_tag on note_tag.tag_id = tagid`. So why is the json not being filtered by `id` when the column gets computed?

I am trying to make a query like this:

```
query notesByTagId {
  notes {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        id
        tags(tagid: "1")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but right now when I execute this query, I get back stringified JSON in the `tags` field. However, all tags are included in the json, whether or not the note actually belongs to that tag or not.

For instance, this note with id = 1 should only have tags with id = 1 and id = 2. Right now it returns every tag in the database

```
{
  "data": {
    "notes": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1",
            "tags": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"Psychology\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"Logic\"},{\"id\":\"3\",\"title\":\"Charisma\"}]",
            ...
```

The key factor with this computed column is that the JSON must include all tags that the note belongs to, even though we are searching for notes on a single `tagid`

here are my simplified tables...

note:

```
create table notes(
  id text, 
  title text
)
```

tag:

```
create table tag(
  id text,
  title text
)
```

note_tag:

```
create table note_tag(
  note_id text FK references note.id
  tag_id text FK references tag.id
)
```

## Update

I am changing up the approach a bit, and am toying with the following function:

```
    create or replace function note_tags(n note)
        returns setof tag as $$
            select tag.*
            from tag
            inner join note_tag on (note_tag.tag_id = tag.id)
            where note_tag.note_id = n.id;
        $$ language sql stable;
```

I am able to retrieve all notes with the `tags` field populated, but now I need to be able to filter out the notes that don't belong to a particular tag, while still retaining all of the tags that belong to a given note.

So the question remains the same as above: how do we filter a table based on a related table's PK?

Answer (score 1):

After a while of digging, I think I've come across a good approach. Based on [this response](https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/issues/26#issuecomment-390055186), I have made a function that returns all `notes` by a given `tagid`.

Here it is:

```
    create or replace function all_notes_with_tag_id(tagid text)
        returns setof note as $$
            select distinct note.*
            from tag
            inner join note_tag on (note_tag.tag_id = tag.id)
            inner join note on (note_tag.note_id = note.id)
            where tag.id = tagid;
        $$ language sql stable;
```

The error in approach was to expect the computed column to do all of the work, whereas its only job should be to get all of the data. This function `all_nuggets_with_bucket_id` can now be called directly in graphql like so:

```
query MyQuery($tagid: String!) {
  allNotesWithTagId(tagid: $tagid) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        tags {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You also might want to look into https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-add-pg-table-condition-plugin/ which allows you to add arbitrary bespoke conditions to your schema.